# Wing panel crashes after elementary os updates

Tags: wingpanel

it takes to nearly about 2 mins for the wing panel to load this is occured after update only. Kindly provide a fix for wing panel in the next update

Comment: it also freezes the entire os

Comment: Thanks for your question , could you open the issue here : https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues?q=is%3Aissue And give some debug logs ? details on your machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Same happening with me too :(

My Logs:

```
Jan 31 20:51:37 x gala.desktop[1486]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x1c00003 (wingpanel)
Jan 31 20:51:37 x wingpanel[1505]: DBusService.vala:64: Service registration suceeded
Jan 31 20:51:38 x dbus-daemon[840]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.73' (uid=1000 pid=1955 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/io.elementary.wingpanel." label="unconfined")
Jan 31 20:51:45 x gala.desktop[1486]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2e00015 (io.element)
Jan 31 20:51:46 x PackageKit: get-packages transaction /366_cdadccee from uid 1000 finished with success after 783ms
Jan 31 20:51:50 x PackageKit: search-name transaction /367_aaadcbea from uid 1000 finished with success after 765ms
Jan 31 20:51:50 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:51:50 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:51:50 x nm-applet[1573]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 31 20:51:50 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:51:50 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:51:50 x nm-applet[1573]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 31 20:52:14 x PackageKit: refresh-cache transaction /368_baaaaabd from uid 1000 finished with cancelled after 24620ms
Jan 31 20:52:17 x PackageKit: search-name transaction /369_ebaaddcb from uid 1000 finished with success after 1987ms
Jan 31 20:52:17 x PackageKit: get-details transaction /370_bedcecda from uid 1000 finished with success after 416ms
Jan 31 20:52:18 x PackageKit: depends-on transaction /371_bcbacecd from uid 1000 finished with success after 416ms
Jan 31 20:52:18 x PackageKit: get-details transaction /372_aeaaaead from uid 1000 finished with success after 419ms
Jan 31 20:52:19 x PackageKit: search-name transaction /373_ccddeebc from uid 1000 finished with success after 457ms
Jan 31 20:52:19 x PackageKit: get-details transaction /374_eacbccea from uid 1000 finished with success after 420ms
Jan 31 20:52:20 x PackageKit: depends-on transaction /375_ebddeedd from uid 1000 finished with success after 419ms
Jan 31 20:52:20 x PackageKit: get-details transaction /376_dcdcccea from uid 1000 finished with success after 419ms
Jan 31 20:52:21 x PackageKit: search-name transaction /377_beacbdbd from uid 1000 finished with success after 452ms
Jan 31 20:52:21 x PackageKit: get-details transaction /378_dcbeaeaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 425ms
Jan 31 20:52:22 x PackageKit: get-packages transaction /379_cedadaeb from uid 1000 finished with success after 645ms
Jan 31 20:52:22 x PackageKit: get-updates transaction /380_acbcbbee from uid 1000 finished with success after 572ms
Jan 31 20:52:53 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:52:53 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:52:53 x nm-applet[1573]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 31 20:52:53 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:52:53 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:52:53 x nm-applet[1573]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 31 20:53:56 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 31 20:53:56 x nm-applet[1573]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Comment: Welcome to the forums. You response does not answer the question. Please post only answers in the answer section. Thanks.